# cucumber-jvm java HelloWorld example OutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I would like some help running the java cucumber ‘hello world’ example found in this package:
***cucumber.examples.java.helloworld.HelloStepdefs***

Am wondering have I missed something in my set-up?

- java version "1.6.0_37"
- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 with m2e plug-in
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber.git 1.1.3-SNAPSHOT

I keep getting the below error:

```
Feature: Hello World  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.indentedLocation(PrettyFormatter.java:142)
    at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.printStep(PrettyFormatter.java:255)
    at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.match(PrettyFormatter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:12)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$2.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:138)
    at $Proxy11.match(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.match(JUnitReporter.java:61)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:250)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:49)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:43)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:36)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:83)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:77)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even  I am facing same issue with 1.1.3 :( just saw this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cukes/rCVf28oK1SI it seems to be a regression issue . i changed version in pom and build files to 1.1.2 and it is working fine now.

Comment: Thanks that resolved it for me too. (Do you see the irony in a test tool not been tested ;) )

Answer (score 1):

this error only happens for me when a formatter is configured, remove it, and all the tests run correctly.

So, remove formatting... and version 1.1.3 works, but you do loose all output ?!